# How to delete or fill 0 in equal cell values between rows in df pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm have two df and I'm compare them and save the data to a xlsx (later will want to json) file. But after comparison, both lines remain and it is difficult to see the changes.

How to remove / fill 0 equal values in two rows with Pandas? I'm have 77 columns in this df.

With this code i'll concat two df and drop duplicate rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df4 = pd.read_excel("output 24.07.2020.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1")
df5 = pd.read_excel("output 25.07.2020.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1")

df_diff = pd.concat([df4, df5], keys=["s1", "s2"]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df_diff.sort_values("tnom", inplace=True)

df_diff.to_excel("different2.xlsx", "sheet1", index=True)
```

Tnank you!

Df example after merging df4 and df5:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':['01','01','33','33','44','44'],
    'user': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Anna'],
    'income': [40000, 40000, 80000, 80000, 77777, 77777],
    'balance':[333, 222, 444, 444, 444, 444],
    'plus':[123,123,321,311,200,200],
    'minus':[15,15,61,61,77,77]})

>>> df
   ID   user  income  balance  plus  minus
0  01    Bob   40000      333   123     15
1  01    Bob   40000      222   123     15
2  33   Jane   80000      444   321     61
3  33   Jane   80000      444   311     61
4  44  Alice   77777      444   200     77
5  44   Anna   77777      444   200     77
```

Wanted DF after fill 0 equal walues:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':['01','01','33','33','44','44'],
    'user': ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'Alice', 'Anna'],
    'income': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'balance':[333, 222, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'plus':[0,0,321,311,0,0],
    'minus':[0,0,0,0,0,0]})

>>> df
    ID   user  income  balance  plus  minus
 0  01      0       0      333     0      0
 1  01      0       0      222     0      0
 2  33      0       0        0   321      0
 3  33      0       0        0   311      0
 4  44  Alice       0        0     0      0
 5  44   Anna       0        0     0      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use:**

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
mask = (
    df.groupby(level=0).transform('count').gt(1) &  
    df.groupby(level=0).transform('nunique').eq(1)
)
df = df.where(~mask, 0).reset_index()
```

---

**Details:**

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `level=0` and `transform` the dataframe using [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and use [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) to create a boolean `mask`.

```
print(mask)
     user  income  balance   plus  minus
ID                                      
01   True    True    False   True   True
01   True    True    False   True   True
33   True    True     True  False   True
33   True    True     True  False   True
44  False    True     True   True   True
44  False    True     True   True   True
```

Use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to replace the values in dataframe with `0` based on this `mask`.

```
print(df)

   ID   user  income  balance  plus  minus
0  01      0       0      333     0      0
1  01      0       0      222     0      0
2  33      0       0        0   321      0
3  33      0       0        0   311      0
4  44  Alice       0        0     0      0
5  44   Anna       0        0     0      0
```

Comment: Shubham Sharma, thank you very much! One question. If I have in first df 3000 rows, in second df 3005 rows. This 5 new rows will be in my new concat df. After using your nice solution I'll have 0 because pandas can't create boolean mask.    How I'm can avoid it and see this 5 rows in new df?? Thank you!

Comment: Lets' discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218574/discussion-data-science).

Comment: Like in this example:                       df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':['01','01','33','33','44','44', '777'],
    'user': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Anna', 'NewOPne'],
    'income': [40000, 40000, 80000, 80000, 77777, 77777, 865],
    'balance':[333, 222, 444, 444, 444, 444, 855],
    'plus':[123,123,321,311,200,200, 70],
    'minus':[15,15,61,61,77,77, 99]})